# Clarifications about the Iwasawa Main Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

I would like to clarify a couple of things regarding the Iwasawa main conjecture.

- [In the paper where Mazur and Wiles prove the main conjecture](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0076?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B185%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D), on page 182, it is written that $h_p(\omega^i, T)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\gamma-1$ acting on $V^{[i]}$. Whereas, [in the Wikipedia article on the main conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_conjecture_of_Iwasawa_theory#:%7E:text=The%20main%20conjecture%20of%20Iwasawa%20theory%20was%20formulated%20as%20an,fields%20by%20Wiles%20(1990).), we have a $\gamma$ instead of $\gamma-1$. Which one is correct?
- The main conjecture asserts that the ideal generated by $h_p(\omega^i, T)$ in $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$ equals the ideal generated by a $p$-adic $L$-function. But, apriori $h_p(\omega^i, T)$ lies in $\mathbb Q_p[T]$, so how do we view it as an element of $\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$?

Comment: The wikipedia article could certainly be improved, but $T=\gamma-1$ is used in both to identify $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}_p[\![\Gamma]\!]$ with $\mathbb{Z}_p[\![T]\!]$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If I understand correctly, $\gamma$ is supposed to be an element of $1+p\mathbb Z_p \subseteq \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$.  So, $\gamma-1$ is not in $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$. I'm a bit confused about this because in the paper the vector space $V$ has an action by $\textrm{Gal}( F_\infty/\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$.

Comment: $T$ lies in the Iwasawa algebra, which is the projective limit of the group rings $\mathbb{Z}_p[G_n]$ with $G_n\cong (1+p\mathbb{Z}_p)/(1+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z})$. As $\gamma$ maps to an element in $G_n$, the group ring element $T = \gamma-1$ is not in $G_n$, it is the formal difference of two group elements. All of this can be learned from a basic text on Iwasawa theory. Lang's or Washington's Cyclotomic Fields for instance.

Comment: I am familiar with the Iwasawa algebra, but Mazur and Wiles do not use the Iwasawa algebra in their statement and view $\gamma$ as an element of $\textrm{Gal}(F_\infty/ \mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$. So my question is:  since $\gamma-1$ is not in $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$ and $V$ has an action of $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$, how do we interpret the action of $\gamma-1$ on $V$?

Comment: $(\gamma-1)(v) = \gamma(v) - v$ as always when you translate an action of a group $G$ on an $R$-module into a $R[G]$-module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification!  Could you please  briefly clarify the second question I asked as well? (if $h_p(\omega^i, T)$) lives in $\mathbb Z_p[T]$)?

Comment: One could state the main conjecture by saying that the fractional ideals in $\mathbb{Q}_p[\![T]\!]$ are equal and then note that the analytic side is integral and hence so is the algebraic side. However, if you read on you will see that they later state things without $\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $h$ is really the characteristic series of a $\Lambda$-module; it is just in the introduction that they aimed to simplfy the exposition. (... and that is my last comment on this page).

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Maybe compile your comments into an answer?